Is it possible to disable/change the border color of the dropdown field in the slicer in Power BI?
I would like this rectangular frame to be transparent/or the same color as the background of the widget underneath.

This ruins the whole look of the report, I don't know how to deal with it :(
In the slicer visualization options in pbi this cannot be changed

Currently, the option to change the border color as you requested isn't available even in the JSON theme visual properties.
You can create an idea on the feature or vote for one if it already exists: https://ideas.powerbi.com/ideas/
